# Autolayout whem view are hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I know that there is 2 approaches when dealing with autolayout and hidden views:

1. Remove hidden view from hierarchy and add it back when needed
2. Change UIViews constraints to ignore hidden view

I have some complex case (imo). Here is my layout[image]

Gray view is container view in my hierarchy on the left.
I have 3 blocks: green, yellow and red. Red and yellow also have titles (see small rects of the same color).

So the problem is that yellow and red could be empty. Adding view back would have rather difficult code (for example adding red):

1. I have to check if yellow block is here
2. I have to set lots of constraints in code. I could easily break my UI by changing constraints on Storyboard and not change it in code.

**I need to hide red/yellow views when there is no info and show them again when there is some info (without reloading whole controller)**
Are there any solutions without that problems?

Comment: You should be able to set some low-priority constraints from Green to the bottom (and from Yellow to the bottom if Red alone can be removed).  They'll be broken with all three views in place, but will operate when the bottom ones are missing.

Comment: @sapi updated my question:I need to hide red/yellow views when there is no info and show them again when there is some info (without reloading whole controller)

Comment: If these views are `UILabel`s, you can try setting the `contentHugging` priority on them to suit your needs. If they're actually `UIView`s, you are going to likely need to write code to do it.

Comment: You might also try breaking down the task -- perhaps creating `UIView` classes and/or child view controllers -- and using a composition pattern approach. Just some thoughts- good luck. : )